# SQL Server returns incorrect XML value for parent node after installation of CU14

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

We recently updated SQL Server from:
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU9-GDR) (KB4293805) - 14.0.3035.2 (X64)
to:
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU14-GDR) (KB4494352) - 14.0.3103.1 (X64)

In one of the extraction jobs we are using SQL like:

```
SELECT
XMLNode_Root.R.value('./@ID', 'INTEGER') AS [SellerID],
CAST(XMLNode_Root.R.value('../@ID', 'VARCHAR(25)') AS BIGINT) AS [ApplicationID]
FROM Stage.LoanAppl_XML AS AD
CROSS APPLY AD.ApplicationXMLPackage.nodes('//MessageResponse/body/Application/Seller') AS XMLNode_Root(R)
OPTION(USE HINT('ENABLE_PARALLEL_PLAN_PREFERENCE'));
```

Recently, on random occasions this select started to return NULL values for ApplicationID column even the ID is defined in the parent.

What is interesting:
1. If I do any change to SQL Select, like change case or add spaces it returns correct values.
2. Running `dbcc freeproccache` solves the problem for some time.

I have execution plan saved before and after clearing cache, but can't post it now.

I wonder if anybody had similar issue and was able to find a solution.

Comment: That sure sounds like something for Microsoft Support.  Does it happen without any DML being ran in between? - Especially with `dbcc freeproccache` being curative.

Comment: I agree on containing support. If you can provide sample that replicates the problem that will also be helpful though.

Comment: And I wonder what would happen with an `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`.  Are there differences in execution plan between the one returning `NULL` vs the working one?  Exporting the plan as xml and using a diff tool may be the easiest way to tell.

Comment: I'm definitely planning to contact support. Problem is so random that it is hard to provide a path to replicate this. @Mitch I exported both plans, there is a lot of differences in text compare, still looking into it. `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` solves the problem, but I don't know if it is a permanent fix.

Comment: Can you supply the execution plans for us to have a look at?

Comment: @MartinSmith Unfortunately can't post now execution plans. I will check with security.

Comment: [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/plan-explorer-better-anonymization/) (free) has a pretty good anonymizer if that may sate security.

Comment: @Mitch thanks, I will try that.

Comment: As a workaround, since your description strongly suggests an intermittent bad plan eventually gets cached that you manually remove, you can use Query Store to force the correct plan for the query once you have it. This is a bit more reliable even than `RECOMPILE`, since there is no hard guarantee that the recompile wouldn't happen at a "bad" time (whatever that is for this query).